# Can a sequent be valid if the conclusion contains atoms that are not in the premise?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, formal-proofs

Is it possible to prove the validity of the following sequent:

$p \vdash (p \to q) \to q$

Here, our premise is that $p$ is True. The conclusion references a new atom, $q$.

I would argue that this is not *valid*, because I cannot deduce a conclusion i.e. I cannot derive a conclusion by means of deduction.
Is my question even the right question to ask?

...Or is there some unexpected conclusion like "it is valid because anything follows yadda yadda"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here is a [Natural Deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Hypothetical_derivations) derivation :

1) $p$ --- premise

2) $p \to q$ --- assumed [a]

3) $q$ --- from 1) and 2) by $\to$-elim

> 4) $(p \to q) \to q$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

---

We may check the validity of the proof in the following way : we assume that the premise is True.

Two cases :

*(i)* if $q$ is True, then also $(p \to q) \to q$ is True.

*(ii)* if $q$ is False, then $(p \to q)$ is False, and thus $(p \to q) \to q$ is again True.

Comment: You did not comment on why an assumption (like your **2)**) may introduce atoms not in the premise (Did you truly deduce $q$?--validity check). That is the crux of my question. Also, I am unfamiliar with the notation `[a]`. Please clarify that.

Comment: @JonathanKomar - an assumption is an assumption... we can assume whatever we want. Obviously, in a proof we assume formulas that are "useful" in order to reach the conclusion.

Comment: @JonathanKomar The notation is a bookmark to keep track of when assumptions are raised and discharged. Here assumption [a] is raised on line 2 and discharged on line 4.